# Magento 2 - change block class in layout

Tags: magento2, layout

I know I can change the template of a block with:

```
<referenceBlock name="copyright">
    <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Dfr_Backend::page/copyright.phtml</argument>
    </action>
</referenceBlock>
```

But how can I change the block class?

Comment: `<action method="setTemplate">` is just need to change template file of block class. You can't change block class using `<action method="setTemplate">`

Answer (score 0):

just keep the same name of the block and change class and template.

Code:

```
<block class="Vendor\Module\Block\Your\Class" name="copyright" template="Dfr_Backend::page/copyright.phtml" />
```

Comment: Then why do we even need `<action method="setTemplate">`, we could do it as well like you did to change the template

Comment: If you want to override template in your custom module then `<action method="setTemplate">` we need. and we can override the only templet using this not the block class.